# Prove that a trigonometric equation has six distinct roots

Tags: trigonometry

Show that,in general,the equation $A \sin^3x+B\cos^3x+c=0 $has six distinct roots,no two of which differ by $2\pi$,and that the tangent of their semi-sum is $-\frac{A}{B}$.

My attempt:

I tried to express it as sixth degree equation.

$A \sin^3x+B\cos^3x+C=0 $

$A \sin^3x+B\cos^3x=-C $

Squaring both sides,

$A^2 \sin^6x+B^2\cos^6x+2AB\sin^3x\cos^3x=C^2 $

Does this prove that this equation has six distinct roots,no two of which differ by $2\pi$ and second part i could not prove.Can someone enlighten me in this problem?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, we have to solve:

$$ A\left(\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\right)^3+B\left(\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\right)^3 = -c $$
that is equivalent to finding the roots of the sixth-degree polynomial:
$$ p(u)=(c+B)+3(c-B)u^2+8A u^3+3(c+B)u^4+(c-B)u^6. $$

I do not agree that this polynomial has in general six real roots: by looking at the coefficients of $u^0,u^1,u^2$ we have that [Newton's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) does not hold, so $p(u)$ may have at most $\color{red}{4}$ real roots, since complex roots come in conjugated pairs.

Comment: [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) also indicates problematic cases. For instance, if $C+B$, $C-B$, and $A$ are all positive, then there are either $2$ negative roots, or none at all. Or, if $A=0$, while $C+B$ and $C-B$ match in sign (but aren't themselves zero), then there are no real roots. And so forth. The possibility of six roots requires that $B+C$ and $B-C$ have different signs.